# Raspberry Pi Networking

Tags: networking, pi-zero-w

I currently have a raspberry pi4B (`p0`) with four raspberry pi Zeros (`p1-4`) all conected to the `pi0` via USB (using usb gadget mode for a network connection). To be specific i'm using a pi [Cluster Hat](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/cluster-hat).

At the moment the `p0` has an IP on my home network of `192.168.1.86`. `p1-4` have IPs of `172.19.181.1-4`.

Accessing `p1-4` from `p0` via the network using their IPs works perfectly. However if I want to access `p1-4` from another desktop computer `desk` then they don't show on the home network. From what I've read this makes sense, as the `172.19.181.x` part of the IP of the `p1-4` defines a new sub net that can't be accessed from outside.

My mental image of how these interconnect is this (not sure if correct):

[image: network]

My question is: is there a way that I can have `desk` communicate directly with `p1-4`? is the whole `p0` and `p1-4` system considered it's own sub network even though there is no seperate router between?

Also, how do the raspberry pis all behave if I remove them from the router's network? Right now the router assigns the `p0` an IP of `192.168.1.86` which `p1-4` use in order to communicate with it, whereas the `p1-4` always have their IP's the same (`172.19.181.1-4`). For now I want to have all the pis on the home network for development, but will eventually want to remove the pi's (0-4) from the network and still have them be able to communicate without worrying about `p0` having it's IP reassigned. Is this possible?

Comment: Also, I'm new to both raspberry pi and networking, go easy!

Comment: Maybe you can configure a network "bridge" so you share the connection of p0 transparently such that each p1-4 receives a ip-address of it's own.

Comment: @participant ace, cheers. I'll have a look ar bridging.

Comment: Don't take to much effort to look for a bridge. As far as I know it isn't possible to add a tethered USB interface to a bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a usual routing problem as used all over the world on the internet. You have two subnets, `192.168.1.0/24` and `172.19.181.0/24` (the bitmasks `/24` are assumed. They are mostly used). All router on your network have to know to which next hop it has to send packages, to get to the destination subnet. The `router` must know that it has to send packages with destination `172.19.181.0/24` to `p0`, its next hop. So you have to set a static route on the `router`. I don't know your router, so I can't say how to do it. Have a look at its configuration options. You must set a static route with  destination network to `172.19.181.0/24` (or `172.19.181.0` netmask `255.255.255.0`) and its corresponding gateway (next hop) to `192.168.1.86`, the ip address of `p0`. On a Linux system this would be set with:

```
router ~$ sudo ip route add 172.19.181.0/24 via 192.168.1.86
```

Because `p0` is working as (another) router now to the subnet `172.19.181.0/24`, it is a bad idea that it has a dynamic ip address. If its ip address is changed by the DHCP server then you have to reconfigure all static routes to it on the network. So it is strongly recommended to give it a static ip address. Be sure that this ip address is not in the ip address pool of the DHCP server that it will give dynamically to devices on the network. As default gateway set the ip address of `router`. You also have to enable **ip forwarding**, so packages from subnet `172.19.181.0/24` are forwarded to subnet `192.168.1.0/24`. This is done with:

```
rpi ~$ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

But this is only transient. On reboot it is lost. Look at your operating system how to set it persistent. On a RaspiOS you uncomment `#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

A static ip address also answers your second question. You can disconnect `p0` from the network without loosing connection to `pi1-4`.

Answer (score 1):

the "router" in your image is most likely a switch. It may be a switching part of an Internet router but it is (probably) still a switch.

I have never used a clusterhat, but as I understand it, there are two ways of configuring the network:

- CNAT, use a separate subnet for the cluster, but nodes are not visible from the outside
- CBRIDGE, all nodes are visible from the network.

As I understand it, these are different images for the nodes.

It is possible to set-up IPtable rules on the cluster controller if you use CNAT images. This will require a bit of tweaking. Also, you will probably need to  set-up a static route on your desktop. If you've never done this, you should probable use CBRIDGE images.